# What is the difference between these two compareTo methods?

Tags: java, overriding, comparable, compareto

I want to understand what is the difference between these two methods? Can they both be used for the same problem? Or are they designed for different cases?

```
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    if (row < o.row) return -1;
    if (row > o.row) return +1;

    if (column < o.column) return -1;
    if (column > o.column) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    int cmp = row - o.row;
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = column - o.column;
    return cmp;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The two methods have similar behavior: they would return a negative value `if row < o.row` and positive value `if row > o.row`. `If row == o.row`, they would return a negative value `if column < o.column` and positive value `if column > o.column`. `If both row==o.row` and `column==o.column`, they would return 0.

This means that both methods can be used to sort a list of `Coordinates`, first by the `row` parameter and then by the `column` parameter.

**However, the first method is safer.**

The second method can fail due to numeric overflow. If, for example the result of `row - o.row` should be smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the actual result of the subtraction will become positive even though `row` is smaller than `o.row`.

Of course, in order not to re-invent the wheel, it would be better to rely on `Integer.compare()` and write:

```
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    int res = Integer.compare(row,o.row);
    return res == 0 ? Integer.compare(column,o.column) : res;
}
```

Comment: Eh, you can get nicer than that `Comparator.comparing(Coordinates::getRow).thenComparing(Coordinates::getColumn).compare(this, that)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about String. Is the first method also safer for String?

Comment: @thpthp that would depend on how the two methods will look for `String`s. Are you doing any subtraction when comparing Strings?